# Auto importing issue from installed npm packages in neovim (only in js not ts)

Tags: neovim, autocompletion, lsp, filetype-typescript

I mainly use Neovim for my MERN stack work and it's been a few days, I have noticed that from some of the installed npm packages of my project, I wasn't able to auto-import the functions or components. Some examples are like: `useDispatch` function from the `react-redux` package, and `<Routes>` tags from the `react-router-dom`, today found the simple `mui` components like `Box`, `Grid`, etc. It's been weird to manually import those and use them. If anyone has or is facing this problem please reach out.

Basically what I want to do when working on react, When I type Rotue it should be able to suggest the route tag from the `react-router-dom`, the same for the `mui` components like `Box` or `Grid`. But it is not showing in the suggestions(autocomplete). Tried to do it with the other neovim distributions, didn't work out.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to Vim :-) I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. It would be helpful if you could give an example of what you do and tell us what you expect and what you get. If some plugin are involved it would be good to know which one. If we are able to reproduce your behavior we have more chance to able to help :-)